# mechanism behind decoration in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Below is an example of decorator in python. I don't quite get how it actually works for the doubly decorated decorator.

```
from functools import update_wrapper
def decorator(d):
    print(d.__name__)
    return lambda fn: update_wrapper(d(fn),fn)

decorator=decorator(decorator) #I don't understand how this works.

@decorator
def n_ary(f):
    print(f.__name__)
    def n_ary_f(x,*args):               
        return x if not args else f(x,n_ary_f(*args))
    return n_ary_f

@n_ary
def seq(x,y):return ('seq',x,y)
```

It seems that the flow should be (I am not sure about it):

1. `decorator` is decorated, so it returns `lambda fn: update_wrapper(decorator(fn),fn)`.
2. `n_ary=decorator(n_ary)`, then `n_ary` is now updated due to the function of `update_wrapper(decorator(n_ary),n_ary)`
3. The third part should be the update of seq, but I don't understand when is the `update_wrapper` function used.

Comment: Can I ask where you found this? This is someone trying to be too clever for little gain, and I'd love to see what their motivation was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decoration is just syntactic sugar for calling another function, and replacing the current function object with the result. The `decorator` dance you are trying to understand is over-using that fact. Even though it tries to make it easier to produce decorators, I find it *doesn't actually add anything* and is only creating confusion by not following standard practice.

To understand what is going on, you can substitute the function calls (including decorators being applied) with their return values, and tracking the `d` references by imagining saved references to the original decorated function object:

1. `decorator=decorator(decorator)` replaces the original `decorator` function with a call to itself. We'll just ignore the `print()` call here to make substitution easier.

   The `decorator(decorator)` call returns `lambda fn:
   update_wrapper(d(fn),fn)`, where `d` is bound to the original
   `decorator`, so now we have

   ```
   _saved_reference_to_decorator = decorator
   decorator = lambda fn: update_wrapper(_saved_reference_to_decorator(fn), fn)
   ```

   so `update_wrapper()` is not actually called yet. It'll only be called when this new `decorator` lambda is called.
2. `@decorator` then calls the above `lambda` (the one calling `_saved_reference_to_decorator(fr)` and passing the result to `update_wrapper()`) and applies that lambda to the `def n_ary(f)` function:

   ```
   n_ary = decorator(n_ary)
   ```

   which expands to:

   ```
   n_ary = update_wrapper(_saved_reference_to_decorator(n_ary), n_ary)
   ```

   which is:

   ```
   _saved_reference_to_n_ary = n_ary
   n_ary = update_wrapper(lambda fn: update_wrapper(_saved_reference_to_n_ary(fn), fn), n_ary)
   ```

   Now, [`update_wrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) just copies metadata from the second argument to the first returning the first argument, so that then leaves:

   ```
   n_ary = lambda fn: update_wrapper(_saved_reference_to_n_ary(fn), fn)
   ```

   with the right `__name__` and such set on the `lambda` function object.
3. `@n_ary` is again a decorator being applied, this time to `def seq(x, y)`, so we get:

   ```
   seq = n_ary(seq)
   ```

   which can be expanded to:

   ```
   seq = update_wrapper(_saved_reference_to_n_ary(seq), seq)
   ```

   which if we take the return value of `update_wrapper()` is

   ```
   seq = _saved_reference_to_n_ary(seq)
   ```

   with the metadata copied over from the original `seq` to whatever the original `n_ary` function returns.

So in the end, all this dance gets you is `update_wrapper()` being applied to the return value from a decorator, which is the contained wrapper function.

This is all way, **way too complicated**. The `update_wrapper()` function has a far more readable helper decorator already provided: [`@functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps). Your piece of code could be rewritten to:

```
import functools

def n_ary(f):
    print(f.__name__)
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def n_ary_f(x,*args):
        return x if not args else f(x,n_ary_f(*args))
    return n_ary_f

@n_ary
def seq(x,y):return ('seq',x,y)
```

I simply replaced the `@decorator` decorator on the `n_ary()` function definition with a `@functools.wraps()` decorator on the contained wrapper function that is returned.